# Approximate medoid using matrix approximation

Tags: clustering, matrix, matrix-decomposition, k-medoids

The medoid of a set of $n$ points is defined as the point that minimizes the average distance to all the other points. If there is a matrix containing rows in which each row is the set of all metric distances between a point and the rest of the points, we are looking for the row with the smallest sum. Finding this row by brute force is of $O(n^2)$ complexity. Is it possible to approximate the matrix first by some approach like Nystrom Method, which is of complexity $O(nmr+r^3)$, where $m$ is the number of anchor points chosen and $r$ is the rank for the approximation. Such an approximation is of the form $UV^T$, where $U$, $V$ are $n \times r$ matrices. Then, with the matrix-vector product $UV^T\mathbb{1}$, it will be possible to compute row sums in $O(nr+mr)$ operations. I understand that the medoid will be approximate. Nevertheless, is this a good approach to get a reasonable point which is somewhere close to the medoid?

Comment: If you don't compute all O(n²) distances, you may easily miss the optimum medoid.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need only an approximate medoid (as an initialization to an optimization algorithm).